# Passing arguments to function (int to size_t)

Tags: c, parameters

In function `writeDmpFile` I'm calling `writeFile`.

Please see the code and the comments.

My problem is size. In  `writeDmpFile` I see it is 380316. I try to pass it to writeFile.

But while stepping here I'm getting very large number(3832907636190596508).

What am I doing wrong. I'd expect, that 380316 will be passed.

```
int writeFile(char *name,  unsigned char *buff, size_t *size,const char *dir )
{
  FILE * pFile;
  chdir (dir);
  pFile = fopen ( name, "wb");
  //(gdb) print *size
  //$5 = 3832907636190596508
  fwrite (buff , sizeof(unsigned char), *size, pFile);
  fclose (pFile);

  return 1;
}
int writeDmpFile(GTree *tree, char *filename)
{
  char dmpfilename[32];

  dmpfilename[0] ='\0';
  dmpParams_t params;
  params.buff[0]   ='\0';
  int size =0;
  params.size=&size ;
  g_tree_foreach(tree, (GTraverseFunc)writeDmpFileLine, &params);
  sprintf (dmpfilename, "InstrumentList_FULL.csv_%.*s", 15, filename);
  //here (gdb) print size
  //$1 = 380316
  writeFile(dmpfilename,  ( unsigned char *)params.buff, ( size_t *)&size , dmpdir);//(size_t *)params.size, dmpdir);
}
```

Comment: You don't actually have to cast. An implicit conversion occurs.

Comment: @ciphermagi there is no implicit conversion between pointer types (except with `void *` and object pointer types)

Comment: @ciphermagi: Does it?

Comment: `fwrite (buff, sizeof(unsigned char)j, *size /*occurs here after dereference*/, pFile);`

Comment: I wonder why `size` is passed by address at all?

Comment: @alk Definitely doesn't need to be edited, so that's a good point.

Comment: @ciphermagi: It should be `fwrite (buff, sizeof(unsigned char)j, *((int *) size), pFile);` then which is really awful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two fundamental problems here.

1. You declared `size` to be an `int`, but really it needs to be a `size_t`. Change its type to `size_t`.
2. You should not be passing the address of `size` to `writeFile`. You should be passing it as a const value param. You don't need to modify it, nor do you. So make that clear in the signature of the function.

As a general rule, any time you encounter a type mismatch compiler error and are tempted to suppress the error with a cast, you are almost certainly making a mistake. The compiler reported an error because you made a mistake. Sure you can shut the compiler up, but experience tells me that the compiler is usually right, and we humans are very good at making mistakes.

So, don't suppress type mismatch compiler errors with casts. Seek to understand why the types don't match and thus resolve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
( size_t *)&size
```

This is bad as `size_t` and `int` are different types with different representations. `size_t` is an alias for an unsigned integer type, often `unsigned long`. Here you should declare  `size` as a `size_t` variable.

Comment: Another nice example why casting wild is bad (not to say dangerous) habit.

Comment: I need to cast cause size is based on sprintf which is int.

Comment: @MaMu in that case convert the `int` to `size_t` (before check it is a positive value), but don't cast pointers.

Comment: Casting to `size_t` and then applying the `&`-operator won't work: `lvalue required as unary ‘&’ operand`. I just tested this (as it had been my intuitive, and therefor unreliable answer ... ;-) @ouah (Btw: I upvoted your comment for the "*don't cast pointers*")

Comment: @alk are you answering my comment, because I'm suggesting to use the correct pointer type (i.e., `size_t *`) without using any cast.

Comment: @ouah: The only way to do this without explicitly declaring an intermediate `size_t` would be to go via a compound: `&(size_t){size})`, wouldn't it?

Comment: @alk yes, this could be an alternative also

Answer (score 1):

Despite the question why the `writeFile()` function insists on takeing the `size` via its address, there are two possiblities to solve this issue:

1. Declare an intermediate `size_t`-typed variable:

   ```
   {
     size_t _s = size;
     writeFile(dmpfilename, (unsigned char *) params.buff, &_s, dmpdir);
   }
   ```
2. Or use a (nice) compound statement:

   ```
   writeFile(dmpfilename, (unsigned char *) params.buff, &((size_t){size}), dmpdir);
   ```

Comment: I have tried to use size_t, but now getting bus error. I have edited the code in my question.

Comment: @MaMu: You really should **not** edit your question, as it is the base for the whole discussion here. And editing it might withdraw the background to lots of answers and comment already given. Roll back you edit. If you want to add something add it as an update, leaving the original content around.

Answer (score 0):

```
( size_t *)&size
```

This is a big mistake which you face while migrating from 32bit system to 64bit system. On 32 bit system this code may work properly as both int and size_t will be of 32 bit. but on 64bit system int will be 32 bit but size_t may be of size 64 bit.

Basically size_t was designed to hold pointer arithmetic. This is the type which is returned from sizeof operator.

For your problems solution better you convert `int size =0;` to `size_t size = 0`